# Graph returned an error: Error validating access token: The session is invalid because the user logged out

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth, facebook-php-sdk

I have made the the facebook app for read facebook user profile wall post data (not facebok page), and i am getting two issues, as follows,

1. Data getting displayed not for every user, only me and my app registered test user timeline data can be visible. how can i see everyone data after authorization of app ?
2. I am generating long lived Access-token (60 days) because i wanted to access user timeline profile data although user is offline or logged-out.

Note: my app is web-based, in development mode, and i am generating longlived token by https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=MYAPP_ID&client_secret=MY_APP_SECRETgrant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=ACCESS_TOKEN_GET_AFTER_APP_ATHORIZATION_BY_USER and only access `user_posts` permission by app.

Comment: 1. You need to submit the required permissions for review, before you can ask normal users for them. 2. Logging out invalidates access tokens. (Logging out of your app, I think, not just out of Facebook in general.)

Comment: Thanks CBroe for answer, 1. I will submit it for review. & 2. so its impossible to access user posts on some another devices ? where user is not logged in. i can store long lived access_token in my db. please confirm me i can access data of user or not without login of their account.

Comment: It is possible to access this data from anywhere, as long as you have a valid access token. But I don’t really understand the whole point here - when the user is using another device, then why not simply log them in on that device? Or are you trying to show those posts to _other_ people? That is something you would have to be extremely careful to begin with, regarding privacy settings etc.

Comment: Actually i am going to ask his username and authorize button, then after click he will allow application for access and i will store access_token in my db, and can i use his username(userid) and access_token to generate feed on devices that is desktop application.